# Panning on FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ FullCalendar to display events in my project.

Everything works fine except when i try to set width in calendar to achieve panning functionality.

Basically, i want to display fullcalendar in full size (using agendaWeek) on PC and if i switch to tablet or re size the browser i want calendar to re-size up-to 500px or 600px and after that it should crop i.e. overflow-x hidden so that i can pan to see the events.

I tried fixing the width of my calendar like:

```
<div id="calendar" style="width: 750px; overflow: hidden;">
</div>
```

but instead it stopped re sizing the calendar. I am not sure how to give a start to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `<style>` tag in the main source code, which defines the width. Use % instead of px should do the resizing trick.

As for panning, I believe it is done with CSS and JS. Here is an example, you can just alter it as necessary.

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/pan-zoom-panels.html